# How to trim the last portion of a filename of a list of files in a given folder

Tags: excel, vba

i need a simple macro that simply trims the ends of all filenames in a folder.

I have a list of 60 files with... "filename_dd-mm.xlsx"

```
filename1_04-04.slsx
filename2_04-04.slsx
filename3_04-04.slsx
etc..
```

The macro should delete the " _dd-mm.xlsx " portion from all the filenames and saves them in that same folder.

Can anyone help me out?

Thank You.

Comment: Can we see your code attempt for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DIR function to loop through files in a folder and the LEFT function to return a given number of characters in a string. You can use the NAME command to rename a file. Come back with a separate question if you have any problems, but you will get a better response if you post the code you have written and where you are having problems or errors